# Could someone explain these cache hits to me? [C]

Tags: c, caching

I have been working on this for weeks. I am so close if I understood how this last part it supposed to work.

So, I have a file which contains:

```
10

20

22

18

E10

210

12
```

Ran with: `./lrucache -m 64 -s 4 -e 0 -b 4 -i address01 -r lru`

Where,

```
m is bit size

2^s is the number of sets

2^e is the number of lines

2^b is the block size
```

I need to find the hit/misses using the LRU (least recently used) algorithm. 18 and 22 should be hits.

With what I have now, I get all misses. Which makes sense to me, because as it goes through the file, **no values are the same**, so every time a new one is added (and LRU ejected), it's just another miss. I've tested by adding another 210 at the end, and that gives me a hit. So my program essentially works, just missing an important part.

I'm leaving out any code because I think I might just be ignorant of a certain part of this. Am I supposed to cache it twice? As in cache it without printing hit/miss, then check again? Because I don't see how I would ever get a hit without repeating values.

Could someone maybe explain to me how 18 and 22 are supposed to be hits?

Comment: *I'm leaving out any code*  Bad idea.  It's not even clear what your code is supposed to do, what's wrong with it, and what it should be doing instead.

Comment: The point of caching is that a whole block of memory spanning some range of addresses will be cached. So, if 22 and 18 are supposed to be hits, but 10 and 20 are misses, it would imply that a block spans 16 _units_. Requesting 10 will cache 10-1f, then 20 will cache 20-2f. Now 22 arrives and is a hit because it's within 20-2f. 18 is within 10-1f which is presumably still cached (is "sets" describing how many blocks are cached at any one time?) I think you should go back and rigorously define what all your parameters actually _mean_ before trying to implement the algorithm.

Comment: @paddy Okay see, any explanation I could find on this said it is a hit if the value requested is the same as what is already in the cache, so this definitely made it a little more clear. Thanks

Comment: Not "same" value necessarily. A cache will typically hold a range of addresses. If your cache stores blocks of 16 bytes, then any request for an address within any block of 16 bytes should resolve to a base address that is a multiple of 16. In other words, that's why requesting '0x22' with cache blocks of 16 would result in a base address of 0x20. You can then check if that base address is in the cache or not.

Comment: You must also consider whether your request will span multiple blocks. It depends how much data you want to pull. _e.g._ if you need to pull 64 bits and for whatever reason it's at address 0x3d which is _not_ 64-bit aligned, then that request will cross a cache boundary, which you probably need to handle.